# Is there any way to change button color which is added in ribbon area using outlook plugin?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I want to change color of the custom button I have added using outlook plugin. This button is visible in ribbon area(in message tab) when user opens new mail item for drafting.

I checked the xml schema for the ribbon and button but it do not have any property which allows the change in button color.
Is there any other way using which I can change the color of the button added in outlook ribbon area?

I want to change button color to user defined color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Outlook always uses the current theme color for the button background. The best you can do is change the icon (which can be updated dynamically).

Comment: Yes, I already have an icon on the button, but I wanted to make that button more eye catchy(sounds ridiculous right? ;) but customer is a king).Is there any way to add border to such buttons as by default these buttons do not have any border?

Comment: Nope, your code has no control over the appearance of the button - in this case the *end user* is the king and they tend to frown upon the "look at me!" UI elements :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported. The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) doesn't provide anything for that.

You can read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))